I got a problem with Overflow (scroll) and overlapping divs
I want the task cards to always be inside of main tag. There will sometimes be just 1 task card, sometimes 20, so I want it to have a scroll, but just inside of the main. Hope you understand, but I also think it's easy to see what my problem is.
Also if you have any other suggestions for my design, don't mind sharing them.


body {
  background: none !important;
}

* {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgb(9, 9, 9);
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#nui {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#screen {
  width: 65%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
}

nav {
  max-height: 7.5%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#profile {
  width: 13%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#profile-picture {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#name {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#close {
  width: 13%;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#close>i {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}

#title {
  font-weight: 600;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#tasks {
  width: 97%;
  height: 95%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.task-card {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info {
  width: 92%;
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* This line evenly spaces elements vertically */
}

.infoElement {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.label {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgb(113, 113, 113);
}

.acceptContainer {
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 92%;
  height: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
}

.accept {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accept:hover {
  background-color: rgb(47, 47, 47);
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nui">
    <div id="screen">
      <nav>
        <div id="profile">
          <img id="profile-picture" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="mugshot">
          <p id="name">Egil Cujick</p>
        </div>
        <p id="title">GoPostal</p>
        <div id="close">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <main>
        <div id="tasks">
          <div class="task-card">
            <div class="info">
              <div class="infoElement">
                <div class="label">
                  <p>Area</p>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                  <p>Downtown</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="infoElement">
                <div class="label">
                  <p>Distance</p>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                  <p>10km</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="infoElement">
                <div class="label">
                  <p>Est. Duration</p>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                  <p>30 minutes</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="infoElement">
                <div class="label">
                  <p>Pick-Ups</p>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                  <p>5</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="infoElement">
                <div class="label">
                  <p>Drop-Offs</p>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                  <p>3</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="infoElement">
                <div class="label">
                  <p>Reward</p>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                  <p>$50</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="infoElement">
                <div class="label">
                  <p>XP</p>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                  <p>100</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="infoElement">
                <div class="label">
                  <p>Truck</p>
                </div>
                <div class="value">
                  <p>Van</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="acceptContainer">
              <button class="accept">Accept</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



Full Source Code

That's better, but there's still room for improvement. You should replace your image sources with those from a placeholder service. You should remove any CSS and other assets that are not directly related to your layout (why are you loading script files in a CSS question?). You should make sure your demo accurately shows your problem. We don't debug other sites or code repositories at SO. Then, be more clear in your description. What is "main tag"? Please revise again to improve your communication.

Please change the #tasks height : 80%  and #screen height : 50%


#tasks {
    width: 97%;
    height: 80%;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 1%;

    overflow-y: scroll;
}


#screen {
    width: 65%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;

    border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
    border-radius: 15px;

    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
}



You should get this desired output below:

I hope this helps!

Thank you for your answer.
However I need the task cards to always be the same height and always show about 9 taskcards (if there are enough to do so)
